# The gdb process terminated unexpectedly. Error codes

Tags: c++, gdb, qt-creator

I'm having this message: `The gdb process terminated unexpectedly (code 3)` while debugging a plain C++ application at Qt Creator.

The problem is that sometimes gdb crashes and sometimes it works. The application consists of one file: `main.cpp.`

If I use `Code::Blocks`, the application works.

The problem is connected with my code, because I've never had this error before.

I have 2 questions:

Where can I find information about the meaning of the error codes? What does `code 3` mean?

How can we cause this gdb error by "bad code"? We can easily cause run-time or compiler error, but how can we make gdb to crash?

Thanks so much for answers